# Cannot access /var/www through FTP

Tags: nginx, ftp, vsftpd

I'm trying to access /var/www through Filezilla but my user can only access files inside of it's home directory.

I've added my user to the www-data group, however it still doesn't allow me the ability to go "up" to the root of the directory, so I can enter /var/www.

```
$ ls -al    
drwxr-xr-x  4 www-data www-data       4096 Apr 15 12:50 .    
drwxr-xr-x 13 root     root           4096 Jan 15 00:04 ..    
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data       4096 Jan 14 23:53 html    
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data        612 Apr 15 12:42 index.html
```

Both my html folder and index.html are owned by www-data.

```
$ groups    
acans cdrom floppy sudo audio dip www-data video plugdev netdev
```

Acans belongs to the `www-data` group, so I'm unsure what I need to do to make Filezilla access `/var/www`.

Comment: "I'm trying to access /var/www" why? Just don't. What you want is an absolute security nightmare. Make a directorywatcher that evaluates what is put into the home directory and mv it to /var/www/ if it is acceptable.

Comment: I guess I'm just used to using Filezilla to add/remove/replace files from my web host and wanted to do the same on my local Ubuntu Machine.

If it's too much of a security risk, I guess I'll just keep using the Webmin File Manager.

Comment: ehm even that I would block myself ;-) Directly putting files into /var/www/ can crash your server: my experience in this is that a full disk is easily reached;even a 1Tb disk. (I host a fileserver with lots of pdfs where users can print  them from the web based software so they do not even put the files on there directy. 5 years of pdfs is 1.6Tb :X ) We now host those files on an sepearate instance and not in /var/www/ ;)

Comment: I ended up going with a shortcut instead of trying to access it directly.

So anything in /home/user/media can be accessed by a shortcut in /var/www/media. I don't know if it's safer, but at least I'm not putting thinks directly into /var/www or accessing it directly.